# MySQL select to return '%H:%i:%s' time duration in %i:%s, with %i taking also total of %H

Tags: mysql

Need MySQL(v8) to convert a '%H:%i:%s' time value string to a %i:%s format which has the %H converted to minutes and added to %i.

E.g. A time string 02:10:25 (2 hours, 10 minutes, 25 seconds) needs to output 130:25 (130 minutes and 25 seconds).

How can this be achieved in a SELECT statement?

The statement required to produce this output is along the lines of:
SELECT TIMEDIFF(date_end, date_start)
FROM table;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert it into seconds and the calculate the parts needed

> ```
> SELECT  CONCAT(ROUND(TIME_TO_SEC('02:10:25')/60,0),':',TIME_TO_SEC('02:10:25')%60) new_time
> ```
>
> ```
> | new_time |
> | :------- |
> | 130:25   |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c17a67f5153b272fed34af15267fb11c)*